# Access to the path 'c:\inetpub\wwwroot\' is denied

Tags: c#, .net, wwwroot

In this file I have my docx files when I give some info it saves it inside docx files, but it did work on my server I was working but now I changed everything to a new server but somehow my system program I'm working is getting this error

Comment: Does it complain when you try to open the file or when you try to save it? Have you given the IIS_IUSRS group the (minimum) needed permissions on the "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\templates\" directory? (Or whatever subdirectory it saves to.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must Add Permissions To that Folder for User.